# How to append to the string array in gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am trying to add array data type using gorm

```
type Token struct {
  Base
  Tags pq.StringArray json:"tags"
}
```

using

```
t.DB.Model(&database.Token{}).Where("address = ?", address).Update(&database.Token{Tags: ["1","2"],})
```

But, I am unable to append a new tag to the data. It is getting replaced..
Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

Has `mpromonet` stated that you are replacing tag but not appending on the existing tags.
Here how you can modify your existing Update statement to make it work

#### Update Token struct definition

```golang
Tags   pq.StringArray `gorm:"type:text[]" json:"tags"`
```

#### With `array_cat` function

```golang
t.DB.Model(&database.Token{})
  .Where("address = ?", address)
  .Update("tags", gorm.Expr("array_cat(tags, ?)", pq.Array([]string{"3","4"})))
```

#### With `||` operator

```golang
t.DB.Model(&database.Token{})
  .Where("address = ?", address)
  .Update("tags", gorm.Expr("tags || ?", pq.Array([]string{"3","4"})))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesnot append, it replace the `Tags` field with `["1","2"]`.
In order to append new tags to existing one, you may proceed like :

```
// read row
t.DB.Model(&database.Token).Where("address = ?", address)
// append new tags
newTags := append(database.Token.Tags, "1", "2")
// update database
t.DB.Model(&database.Token).Update("tags", newTags)
```