# Getting Data in PostgreSQL Gorm

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I Have my model as follows:

```golang
package models

import "github.com/lib/pq"

type Guild struct {
    Id               string         `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    DefaultBitrate   int            `json:"defaultBitrate"`
    DefaultState     string         `json:"defaultState"`
    DefaultCategory  string         `json:"defaultCategory"`
    DefaultUserLimit int            `json:"defaultUserLimit"`
    HelpChannel      string         `json:"helpChannel"`
    Generators       pq.StringArray `json:"generators" gorm:"type:text[]"`
    Channels         pq.StringArray `json:"channels" gorm:"type:text[]"`
}
```

Functions File:

```golang
func (h handler) CreateGuild(guildid string) error {
    guild := &models.Guild{
        Id:             guildid,
        DefaultBitrate: "64",
    }
    if result := h.DB.Create(&guild); result.Error != nil {
        return result.Error
    }
    return nil
}
func (h handler) GetGuild(guildid string) (models.Guild, error) {
    var guild models.Guild
    if result := h.DB.First(&guild, guildid); result.Error != nil {
        return guild, result.Error
    }
    return guild, nil
}
```

So What i do is i create a guild first and then try to get it with the same id yet i don't get anything logged in the console

```golang
Database := db.Init()
    h := dbhandlers.New(Database)
    data, err := h.GetGuild("71728137382983743892")
    fmt.Print(data.DefaultBitrate)
```

Github: https://github.com/apidev234/abred

Note: I have already created the guild as such:

```
 err := h.CreateGuild("71728137382983743892")
```

Debugs:

```
2022/03/24 13:37:23 /Users/gaurish/Desktop/Coding/TempVC-Bot/database/handlers/Functions.go:12 SLOW SQL >= 200ms
[1126.461ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO "guilds" ("id","default_bitrate","default_state","default_category","default_user_limit","help_channel") VALUES ('ASDHA','64','','',0,'')
```

```
2022/03/24 13:37:44 /Users/gaurish/Desktop/Coding/TempVC-Bot/database/handlers/Functions.go:19 ERROR: column "asdha" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42703)
[229.439ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "guilds" WHERE ASDHA ORDER BY "guilds"."id" LIMIT 1
```

Array:

```golang
func (h Handler) NewGenerator(guildid string, channelid string) {
    guild := models.Guild{
        Id: guildid,
    }
    if result := h.DB.First(&guild, "id = ?", guildid).Update("generators", append(guild.Generators, channelid)); result.Error != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `CreateGuild` method is not using the given `guildid` in any way. How is gorm supposed to know the id that you want to assign to the created Guild?

Comment: My model does that

Comment: Include that code in the question.

Comment: The github link has the model, Also i updated my createGuild function check that once... Even the question has the model.. the very first codeblock

Comment: Also you can turn on [debugging](https://gorm.io/docs/session.html#Debug) to see the executed SQL queries, it should show you the INSERT query generated for the `Create(&guild)` call and you should see if the `guildid` is being used or not.

Comment: Yes, Debugging is on Guildid is being used..
Updating Question For Debug Logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243272/discussion-between-gaurish-and-mkopriva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `First` with non-number primary keys you need to explicitly specify the column against which you want to match the primary key.

Official [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-objects-with-primary-key):

> If the primary key is a string (for example, like a uuid), the query
> will be written as follows:
>
> ```golang
> db.First(&user, "id = ?", "1b74413f-f3b8-409f-ac47-e8c062e3472a")
> // SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = "1b74413f-f3b8-409f-ac47-e8c062e3472a";
> ```

So in `GetGuild` this:

```golang
h.DB.First(&guild, guildid)
```

should be this:

```golang
h.DB.First(&guild, "id = ?", guildid)
```

Comment: Also, I wanted to know.. Currently every single query to database is logged, I don't want any query to be logged. I tried checking the docs but couldn't find anything regarding disabling the queries to be logged.. Any way to do this?

Comment: I believe you just need to turn of the Debug mode

Comment: Alright.. Probably doing silent mode would help

Comment: @Gaurish Or you can directly change the logger's log level to a `db.Logger.LogMode(logger.Silent)`

Comment: Yeah.. Could also be done while initalizing throught gorm's config...

Comment: Also, i wanted to know how can i push to an array with gorm? Its a text array..Just in the guild model

Comment: @Gaurish for such types, as far as I know, you need to use declared types that implement the [`sql.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.17.8#Scanner) and [`driver.Valuer`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql/driver@go1.17.8#Valuer) interfaces and those implementation transform the Go type from/to the PostgreSQL type. For an example you can take a look at [`lib/pq.StringArray`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lib/pq#StringArray) (you can change `[]string` in your `Guild` to be `pq.StringArray` if you don't want to write your own implementations).

Comment: @Gaurish https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#Implements-Customized-Data-Type

Comment: Yet, I am unable to figure out with the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68143902/17277857

I Updated the question with how am i doing that... Please check the last codeblock once... The array still remains empty...